# How can I improve the performance of my data cleaning code that currently uses ddply by using data.table?

Tags: performance, r, data.table, plyr

I am trying to clean data using ddply but it is running very slowly on 1.3M rows.

Sample code:

```
#Create Sample Data Frame
num_rows <- 10000
df <- data.frame(id=sample(1:20, num_rows, replace=T), 
                Consumption=sample(-20:20, num_rows, replace=T), 
                StartDate=as.Date(sample(15000:15020, num_rows, replace=T), origin = "1970-01-01"))
df$EndDate <- df$StartDate + 90
#df <- df[order(df$id, df$StartDate, df$Consumption),]
#Are values negative? 
# Needed for subsetting in ddply rows with same positive and negative values
df$Neg <- ifelse(df$Consumption < 0, -1, 1)
df$Consumption <- abs(df$Consumption)
```

I have written a function to remove rows where there is a consumption value in one row that is identical but negative to a consumption value in another row (for the same id).

```
#Remove rows from a data frame where there is an equal but opposite consumption value
#Should ensure only one negative value is removed for each positive one. 
clean_negatives <- function(x3){
  copies <- abs(sum(x3$Neg))
  sgn <- ifelse(sum(x3$Neg) <0, -1, 1) 
  x3 <- x3[0:copies,]
  x3$Consumption <- sgn*x3$Consumption
  x3$Neg <- NULL
  x3}
```

I then use ddply to apply that function to remove these erroneous rows in the data

```
ptm <- proc.time()
df_cleaned <- ddply(df, .(id,StartDate, EndDate, Consumption),
                    function(x){clean_negatives(x)})
proc.time() - ptm
```

I was hoping I could use data.table to make this go faster but I couldn't work out how to employ data.table to help.

With 1.3M rows, so far it is taking my desktop all day to compute and still hasn't finished.

Comment: In the natural language description you have not explained operations on date values and why there is a "+90" in the code. Also you can replace `df$Neg <- ifelse(df$Consumption < 0, -1, 1)` with `df$Neg <- sign(df$Consumption)`. You really should NOT overwrite df$Consumption.

Comment: Ouch, a minus 1 for my first question. Sorry, I was trying to generate data that looked like mine but was easily reproducible and scalable. I thought this would be better than an anonymised dput dump. I do have a few more columns in my real data which is why the ddply function appear to call all columns in this example. Thanks for the sign function, much nicer. To avoid writing over $Consumption, are you suggesting that I create a new non-signed $Consumption column or is there a way to aggregate in ddply ignoring the sign of the value in a column ie abs(“Consumption)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question asks about `data.table` implementation. So, I've shown it here. Your function could be drastically simplified as well. You can first get the `sign` by summing up `Neg` and then filter the table and then multiply `Consumption` by `sign` (as shown below).

```
require(data.table)
# get the data.table in dt
dt <- data.table(df, key = c("id", "StartDate", "EndDate", "Consumption"))
# first obtain the sign directly
dt <- dt[, sign := sign(sum(Neg)), by = c("id", "StartDate", "EndDate", "Consumption")]
# then filter by abs(sum(Neg))
dt.fil <- dt[, .SD[seq_len(abs(sum(Neg)))], by = c("id", "StartDate", "EndDate", "Consumption")]
# modifying for final output (line commented after Statquant's comment
# dt.fil$Consumption <- dt.fil$Consumption * dt.fil$sign
dt.fil[, Consumption := (Consumption*sign)]
dt.fil <- subset(dt.fil, select=-c(Neg, sign))
```

---

**Benchmarking**

- The data with million rows:

  ```
  #Create Sample Data Frame
  num_rows <- 1e6
  df <- data.frame(id=sample(1:20, num_rows, replace=T), 
                  Consumption=sample(-20:20, num_rows, replace=T), 
                  StartDate=as.Date(sample(15000:15020, num_rows, replace=T), origin = "1970-01-01"))
  df$EndDate <- df$StartDate + 90
  df$Neg <- ifelse(df$Consumption < 0, -1, 1)
  df$Consumption <- abs(df$Consumption)
  ```
- The `data.table` function:

  ```
  FUN.DT <- function() {
      require(data.table)
      dt <- data.table(df, key=c("id", "StartDate", "EndDate", "Consumption"))
      dt <- dt[, sign := sign(sum(Neg)), 
                 by = c("id", "StartDate", "EndDate", "Consumption")]
      dt.fil <- dt[, .SD[seq_len(abs(sum(Neg)))], 
                 by=c("id", "StartDate", "EndDate", "Consumption")]
      dt.fil[, Consumption := (Consumption*sign)]
      dt.fil <- subset(dt.fil, select=-c(Neg, sign))
  }
  ```
- Your function with `ddply`

  ```
  FUN.PLYR <- function() {
      require(plyr)
      clean_negatives <- function(x3) {
          copies <- abs(sum(x3$Neg))
          sgn <- ifelse(sum(x3$Neg) <0, -1, 1) 
          x3 <- x3[0:copies,]
          x3$Consumption <- sgn*x3$Consumption
          x3$Neg <- NULL
          x3
      }
      df_cleaned <- ddply(df, .(id, StartDate, EndDate, Consumption), 
                             function(x) clean_negatives(x))
  }
  ```
- Benchmarking with `rbenchmark` (with 1 run only)

  ```
  require(rbenchmark)
  benchmark(FUN.DT(), FUN.PLYR(), replications = 1, order = "elapsed")

          test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
  1   FUN.DT()            1   6.137    1.000     5.926    0.211          0         0
  2 FUN.PLYR()            1 242.268   39.477   152.855    82.881         0         0
  ```

My `data.table` implementation is about 39 times faster than your current `plyr` implementation (I compare mine to your implementation because the functions are different).

`Note:` I loaded the packages within the function in order to obtain the complete time to obtain the result. Also, for the same reason I converted the `data.frame` to `data.table` with keys inside the benchmarking function. This is therefore the minimum speed-up.

Comment: @-Arun: doing `dt.fil$Consumption <- dt.fil$Consumption * dt.fil$sign` you are doing a copy of the whole table. You should prefer `dt.fil[,Consumption:=(Consumption*sign)]` which update by reference.

Comment: @Arun, that is amazing and runs almost 100 times faster (4 min compared with 7 hours). There is one slight difference in that values with zero $Consumption are also removed. I was oringally keeping them and cleaning out only those that were replicated in $StartDate and $EndDate as well.

Comment: @Arun, Sorry in retrospect my questions wasnt very clear. I have been generally subsetting with ddply and running a function on each subset e.g.     ddply(df, .(id,StartDate, EndDate, Consumption),function(x){clean_negatives(x)})  <br/> In general, is it possible to acheive the same thing using data.table? For example    dt[, clean_negatives(x), by = c("ACTEW_ID", "StartDate", "EndDate", "Consumption")]

Comment: @Arun, just for info the last line `dt.fil <- subset(dt.fil, select=-c(Neg, sign))` has a more data.table centric expression `dt.fil[,c("Neg","sign"):=NULL]` but `data.table:::subset` does not copy so it is equivalent...